# Unable to merge staging website data to main website Magento 1.13.02

Tags: magento, merge, access-violation, magento-1.13

I'm using a magento 1.13.02 version and there is a feature called staging website in it. In which we can create some products in staging website and test them if we feel satisfy than we can merge them to main website.

When I try to merge the sites I got following log

```
*>     Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails
> (`backup_magentocuat2`.`s_2b_11_catalog_product_website`, CONSTRAINT
> `FK_S_2B_11_CAT_PRD_WS_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
> (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_)
>     Trace: #0 /var/www/canon_staging/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
> Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)*
```

Comment: When you export database, checked the checkbox of foreign key checks

Comment: you mean to set  `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

i have try this but its the same error log

Comment: hello, if you have wholesatabase why not create new one